# Webdriver object has no attribute 'prefs'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I am attempting to write a class of web-drivers for automation purpose.

```
class WebDriver(object):
    def __init__(self, browser, *args):
        if browser=='Firefox': self.id= 1
        else: self.id= 2
        try:
            self.set_prefs()
            print("prefrences are set:", self.set_prefs)
        except Exception as e:
            print("ERROR: ",e)

        try:
            self.set_options()
            print("Options are set:", self.options)
        except Exception as e:
            print("ERROR: ",e)

    def start_driver(self):
        if self.id==1:
            self.driver= webdriver.Firefox()
        else:
            self.driver= webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options= self.options)

    def set_options(self):
        if self.id==1:
            self.options= webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        else:
            self.options= webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            self.options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
            self.options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
            self.options.add_experimental_option("prefs", self.prefs)

    def set_prefs(self):
        if self.id==1:
            self.set_prefs= None
        else:
            self.set_prefs={
                "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
                "download.default_directory": os.getcwd()+"\\Software_Output\\", 
                "directory_upgrade": True,
            }   

    def close_driver(self):
        self.driver.close()
```

But I get below error:
'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'prefs'
for code line

```
self.options.add_experimental_option("prefs", self.prefs)
```

Am I missing something? 
Also, is this model correct(setting pref->options->defining drivers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.prefs` is not defined anywhere.

You have this code here:

```
def set_prefs(self):
        if self.id==1:
            self.set_prefs= None
        else:
            self.set_prefs={
                "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
                "download.default_directory": os.getcwd()+"\\Software_Output\\", 
                "directory_upgrade": True,
            }
```

I think what you meant is:

```
def set_prefs(self):
        if self.id==1:
            self.prefs= None
        else:
            self.prefs={
                "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
                "download.default_directory": os.getcwd()+"\\Software_Output\\", 
                "directory_upgrade": True,
            }
```